# bash script to find all files where date in filename is newer than current date and time

Tags: linux, bash

I'm new to bash so I'm having a bit of trouble coming up with the correct syntax for this. But the gist is that I need to loop through all of the files in a certain directory and print the one's where the date and time in the filename are in the future.

Filename syntax is as follows:

2016-04-27_19EST-KST.txt

2016-04-28_02EST-MSK.txt

2016-04-28_03EST-CET.txt

2016-04-28_09EST-EST.txt

2016-04-28_10EST-CST.txt

2016-04-28_12EST-PST.txt

The hour of the day being in military format and where I don't care about the last "EST-CST" portion.

This is what I've got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

curdate=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
curtime=$(date +%H)

for fn in *.txt;do
        [ "${curdate}_${curtime}*.txt" "<" "$fn" ] && continue
        echo "$fn"
done
```

This just returns all files in the directory. What I'm I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is close but it is better to use numerical comparison to compare the dates and normalize the date representation using `date`, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
curdate=$(date +%Y%m%d%H)

for fn in *.txt; do
    tmp=${fn%%EST*}  # remove timezone info, ignored
    fdate=$(date -d "${tmp/_/ }" +%Y%m%d%H)
    (( curdate < fdate )) && echo "$fn"
done
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and I think it's the cleanest solution. Thank you

Comment: Furthermore, how would I go about hard coding a specific directory here? ...let's say I want to look for these files in /opt/test/import only

Answer (score 2):

This script will print all files whose names represent dates newer than the present:

```
#!/bin/bash
d="$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%HZZZ.tmp.txt)"
touch "$d"
printf "%s\n" *.txt | LC_ALL=C sort | awk -v d="$d" 'f{print} d==$0{f=1}'
rm "$d"
```

#### How it works

- `d="$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%HZZZ.tmp.txt)"`

  This creates a name that matches the current time.
- `touch "$d"`

  This creates a file with name matching the current time.
- `printf "%s\n" *.txt`

  This prints all `*.txt` filenames, one per line, to stdout.

  (Your files all have sensible names.  If any were to have newlines in their names, then we would want to replace this newline-separated list with a null-separated list and make appropriate changes to the code below.)
- `LC_ALL=C sort`

  This sorts the file names into order.  I specify `LC_ALL=C` so to assure that the order is what one expects.

  At this point, note the `ZZZ` that we used in the temporary file name.  This assures that temporary file sorts after any other files with the current 
  hour.  If we wanted to include files with the current hour in the output, we might use `AAA` instead.
- `awk -v d="$d" 'f{print} d==$0{f=1}'`

  This code prints all file names *after* our temporary with the current time.
- `rm "$d"`

  This deletes the no-longer-needed temporary file.

#### Improvement

If the above script were to be interrupted in progress, it would leave a stray file in the directory.  This might happen if, for example, Ctrl-C was pressed while the script was running.   To make sure that that file is always removed, we can use a `trap`:

```
#!/bin/bash
d="$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%HZZZ.tmp.txt)"
trap 'rm "$d"' EXIT
touch "$d"
printf "%s\n" *.txt | LC_ALL=C sort | awk -v d="$d" 'f{print} d==$0{f=1}'
```

Comment: Sorry if I misspoke by saying "print", but I'd like to view the results in console after running like echo. How would I update this to use echo instead of printing to stdout? ...or if it is easier how do I view the results as I am very new to the Linux command line? Thanks

Comment: @Lars This should work just like `echo`.  Printing to stdout is exactly what `echo` does.

Comment: Ah ok. I'm just not seeing any results as there are probably no future files in my directory at this time. I will mark this as answer. Thank you for a clear and detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

At some point you might need to parse the date using awk or sed or something.  You can try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

curdate=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
curtime=$(date +%H)

for fn in *.txt;do
    date=$(echo $fn | sed 's/EST.*.txt//')
    if [[ "${curdate}_${curtime}" < "$date" ]]; then
        echo $fn
    fi
done
```

NOTE: Please keep in mind that the sed command is quite specific.  This will only work if the filenames will **always** be in the format you posted.  You can adjust it though to suit your needs.